# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

Tags: python

Что это? При попытке открыть скрипт выдает нижеприведенную ошибку... Помогите кто, чем может :)

```
from Tkinter import *  
from tkFileDialog import *

def opent():  
    files = askopenfile(filetypes = [("Python source file",
                                                 ".py")])  
    text.insert("1.0", open(files).read())

tk = Tk()
text = Text(tk)
text.pack()
but = Button(tk, text="open", command=opent)
but.pack()
tk.mainloop()

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\YURA\Рабочий стол\hhh.py", line 8, in opent
    text.insert("1.0", open(files).read())
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

Comment: Хотя с

   LoadFileDialog(self.winlist[0].tk).go(dir_or_file = \
                                                            programm_path +
                                                            "\\My Projects\\",
                                                            pattern='*.py')
    text.insert("1.0", open(select_file).read())

такой ошибки не возникает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

Переменная `files` не `string` или `buffer`, вестимо. Смотрите, что возвращает функция `askopenfile()`

[tkFileDialog](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте переложить скрипт в папку где в названии не присутствует русских символов.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте запустить все это из папки без пробелов и русских букв имени.

Comment: Боже мой, причем тут имена папки, когда python русским по белому говорит, что в `open()` был передан объект типа `file`, в то время как ожидаться тип `string` или `buffer` ?

Comment: Русские символы  непричем, ибо это пример... Рабочий вариант программы в которой возникает эта ошибка лежит в папке с установленным Питоном под именем IDLE... Так что...

Comment: @Xyanight, это вопрос к @dword и @Vorlog был. А у вас банально перепутаны методы, смотрите [ссылку](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog) в моем ответе.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov да, вы правы, меня смутило Unicode.

Comment: Ничего у меня не перепутанно!

Comment: files в данном случае не  является строкой к файлу... но и вставить в Text его не выходит.

Comment: > open a file
>
> askopenfile(mode='r', **options)
>
>
> 
> get a filename to open
>
> askopenfilename(**options)

@Xyanight, чувствуете разницу?

Comment: askopenfilename, правильно, возвращает строку. Но тогда возникает еще другая ошибка:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IDLE\IDLE.py", line 128,  in <module>
        tk.mainloop()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1017, in mainloop
        self.tk.mainloop(n)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1412, in __call__
        raise SystemExit, msg
    SystemExit